# How to open a save file dialogue box and save the file by writing a string into it in libreoffice.Below code is in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, libreoffice

I get the following error when I run the below vba code in libreoffice

BASIC runtime error.
'423'
GetSaveAsFilename

```
' Comment Code starts from here    

Sub Buildyaml()   
     Dim yaml as string          
      yaml = "Hello World"  
  Dim vFile As Variant  

'opening the save as box

        vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Sheets("SIMPLE").Cells(2, 2) & "_config.yaml", _
        FileFilter:="YAML Config File (*.yaml), *.xlsb, All files (*.*), *.*", _
        Title:="Save Config File As:")
        If vFile <> False Then
            Call saveFile(vFile, yaml)
            MsgBox ("File Saved")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Saving to file

```
Sub saveFile(fileName As Variant, content As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
    Dim oFile As Object       
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName)            
    oFile.WriteLine content
    oFile.Close            
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the libreoffice calc equivalent to your VBA macro.

```
sub Buildyaml()

 dim yaml as string
 yaml = "Hello World"

 dim aDialogTyp(0)
 aDialogTyp(0) = com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.TemplateDescription.FILESAVE_AUTOEXTENSION

 oDialog=createunoservice("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker")
 oDialog.initialize(aDialogTyp())
 oDialog.appendFilter("YAML Config File (*.yaml)","*.yaml")
 oDialog.appendFilter("All files (*.*)","*.*")
 oDialog.setTitle("Save Config File As:")

 oDialog.execute
 if ubound(oDialog.Files) < 0 then 
  sFileName =""
 else 
  sFileName=oDialog.Files(0)
 end if
 sFiltername=oDialog.CurrentFilter
 if sFilename <> "" then
  call saveFile(sFilename, yaml)
  MsgBox "File Saved"
 end if
end sub

sub saveFile(sfileName as string, sContent as string)
 oSimpleFileAccess = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")
 oOutputStream = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.io.TextOutputStream")
 oOutputStream.setOutputStream(oSimpleFileAccess.openFileWrite(sFileName))
 oOutputStream.writeString(sContent)
end sub
```

Save the File with a fixed file name in the path where the calc document is stored:

```
sub Buildyaml2()

 dim yaml as string
 yaml = "Hello World"

 GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
 sPath=DirectoryNameoutofPath(ThisComponent.getURL(), "/")
 sFileName = "test.yaml"

 call saveFile(sPath & "/" & sFilename, yaml)
 MsgBox "File Saved"

end sub
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Hi Axel, How can I modify the above code to save this file to current directory where the excel resides and hard coded name. I dont want the prompt. Just  want to save the file in current directory and with specific name . I know in VBA you thisworkbook.path which gives you the workbook path, Curious to know How can I write the above code to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See example in my answer.

Comment: I got the following error on running that code provided by you.  BASIC runtime error.
'35'
saveFile

Comment: Then the `sub saveFile(sfileName as string, sContent as string)` is not present. This sub is needed and the same as before.

Comment: Quick question, When I make any changes in my excel spreadsheet, the text file I am generating doesn't reflect those changes basically its not overwriting the file if any changes are there. if I save the changes with different name then its working but for the same name its not over writing. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The `sub saveFile(sfileName as string, sContent as string)` will overwrite existent files with the given content. It does this if the operating system will allow this. That is, if the existent file is locked because another process got exclusive access to it, then the sub will produce an error. So if your program not overwrites the file, I suspect this file is opened in another program.